# How can I offset a 5 minute countdown interval timer by 1 minute, using react JS

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, next.js, setinterval, ecmascript-2016

I am looking to make a 5-minute interval timer in react JS, that's offset by 1 minute. 
The timer I have below lands at 1:00 => 1:05 => 1:10 => 1:15 => 1:20. 
I need this to be offset to 1:01 => 1:06 => 1:11 => 1:16 => 1:21. 
The timer needs to be in-sync with the Los Angeles time-zone. 
Looking for the cleanest es7 code if possible. 
I am using NextJS framework. 
This is the code I have so far.

```
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState("")

  const secondPassed = useCallback( () => {
    const cur_date = new Date();
    const minutes = cur_date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = cur_date.getSeconds();
    console.log( (4 - minutes % 5) + ":" + (seconds >= 50 ? "0" : "") + (59 - seconds))
    setTimer( `${(4 - minutes % 5) + ":" + (seconds >= 50 ? "0" : "") + (59 - seconds)}` )
  },[])
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    setInterval(secondPassed, 1000)
  },[])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offset the starting date by 1 minute.

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState("")

  const secondPassed = useCallback( () => {
    const cur_date = new Date( Date.now() - 1000 * 60 );
    const minutes = cur_date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = cur_date.getSeconds();
    console.log( (4 - (minutes % 5)) + ":" + (seconds >= 50 ? "0" : "") + (59 - seconds))
    setTimer( `${(4 - (minutes % 5)) + ":" + (seconds >= 50 ? "0" : "") + (59 - seconds)}` )
  },[])
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const run = setInterval(secondPassed, 5000)
    return () => clearInterval(run)
  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [time, settime] = useState()

const cur_date = new Date();
const minutes = cur_date.getMinutes();
const seconds = cur_date.getSeconds();

if(minutes === "your timing start") {
settime(minutes) }

if(minutes ==== time + 5 ) {
settime(minutes)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Comment: This does not answer my question.